# Set NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to set NLS_COMP and NLS_SORT for the current session to check if it will make a difference with regards to some SQL query I am running that is case sensitive, for some reason the parameters will not change
what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters where parameter in ('NLS_COMP','NLS_SORT');
>>>    NLS_SORT BINARY
>>>    NLS_COMP BINARY

SELECT * FROM nls_instance_parameters where parameter in ('NLS_COMP','NLS_SORT');
>>>    NLS_SORT NULL
>>>    NLS_COMP BINARY

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
>>>session SET altered.
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;
>>>session SET altered.

SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters where parameter in ('NLS_COMP','NLS_SORT');
>>>    NLS_SORT BINARY
>>>    NLS_COMP BINARY

SELECT * FROM nls_instance_parameters where parameter in     ('NLS_COMP','NLS_SORT');
>>>    NLS_SORT NULL
>>>    NLS_COMP BINARY
```

Comment: Or alternatively nls_session_parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the **session** values but reading the **system** ones. Try reading from `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_COMP', 'NLS_SORT');
```